# Why EKS pods referring to old artifactory image address?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, nexus, docker-image

We migrated our docker image artifactory from the self-hosted Nexus on EC2 to the ECR repository and updated the new image reference in all the deployments. But many times we observed that when the pod is recreated or deployment is restarted the pod fails with the **imagepullbackoff** error because it is referring to the old image reference which does not exist whereas its deployment contains the new image reference. Then we have to manually update the new image reference in the pod which is not the correct way. Does anybody know why this behavior is happening?

Answer (score 0):

when changing the container image name or tag you would just scale your application to 0 and back to the original size means all pods will be deleted and recreated so image tags will be updated in every pod you can do it by :

```
kubectl scale --replicas=0 deployment my-deployment
```

Ensure you set `ImagePullPolicy: Always` and kill each pod and have the deployment recreate it. this step is not required for  local images.

Now update the image simple way is by using following command:

```
kubectl set image deployment/my-deployment mycontainer=myimage
```

Now scale up the deployment using the below command ensure you have matched the replica count before and after updating image

```
kubectl scale --replicas=1 deployment application
```

Now check if **imagepullbackoff** error repeats now.

Comment: Hello, @sai thanks for your feedback. But this is just the procedure to change the image. My question is sometimes new pods refer to the old image even after following this method. Although in our case we do changes in the deployment via Jenkins pipeline and when that is done, all the new pods are created and old pods are deleted.